# Проблема с сайтом

Tags: html, css

уважаемые. Заметил дилемму такого рода: загрузил сайт на хостинг, на ПК в Dev Tools всё отлично (выбираю размер экрана как на IPhone 7), но когда захожу на этот же сайт с телефона (тот же IPhone 7) - сайт отображается не совсем так, как на пк в Dev Tools.

Ниже приведу пример, на **скриншоте #1** (ПК) есть желтый border при фокусе, та и вообще там есть только нижняя рамка, без закругления. На **скриншоте #2, 3** (IPhone 7) у этой рамки появляется закругление и кнопка ведет себя по-другому.

Прошу помощи, как это можно решить?
[image: Скриншот #1]
[image: Скриншот #2]
[image: Скриншот #3]

код кнопки:

```css
.signUp__button {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 20px;
      padding: .2em 1.5em .2em 1.5em;
      margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<button class="signUp__button">SIGN UP</button>
```

Comment: код кнопки в студию

Comment: На счёт "Register", не обращайте внимание, сам не совсем заметил, что написал :)

Comment: <button class="signUp__button">SIGN UP</button>

Comment: `.signUp__button {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding: .2em 1.5em .2em 1.5em;
 margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}`

Comment: Мне интересно больше всего разница, при запуске на ПК в дев тулс и на смартфоне, одного и того же сайта. Этой разницы не должно было быть, но я не знаю в чём дело...

Comment: вижу, что у Вас в стилях кнопки закругленные границы кнопки (`border-radius: 20px;`). если Вы хотели добиться того, чтобы у кнопки была лишь одна нижняя граница, то перепишите код (!)

Comment: Вы, наверное, не правильно поняли. Поле input другое.

Answer (score 1):

я понял о чём Вы спрашиваете.

у каждого браузера своё отображение нативных элементов (таких как `button`, `input`, `select` и т.д). все они **немного** отличаются стилистическим оформление, как в Вашем случае. это происходит из-за того, что у браузеров разные движки для отображения страниц (еще у каждого движка есть свои разные порты, но это не важно) и даже разный `ShadowDOM`. если Вы будете просматривать стили вашего элемента в **DevTool**, Вы можете увидеть стили `user agent stylesheet`. именно эти **заводские** стили браузер задает своим нативным элементам.

чтобы изменить/убрать их, нужно перебить заводские стили своими стилями. в Вашем случае просто каждому `input type="text"` задайте стиль `border-radius: none`. таким образом Вы перепишете заводские стили.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Это стандартная проблема кросбраузерности, все браузеры имеют свои предустановки стилей стандартных элементов. Для решения проблемы используют reset.css, вот например такой:

```
https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6
```

он перезаписывает стили стандартных элементов. Вот и всё